# how to create label for facebook broadcast message using facebook's broadcast api?

Tags: facebook, broadcast, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to create a custom label for broadcast message using facebook's [broadcast api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts)

I'm able to create label for by doing as instructed in documentation however i get an array of ids in response instead a single id for my custom label , this is how i'm requesting api

```
function createlabel(token, getlabel) {
var labels;
 var options = {
 name: "firstbroadcast",
 uri: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/custom_labels?",
 qs: {
  access_token: token
 },
 json: true,
}
requestpromise(options).then(function (label) {
console.log('returned label', label);
labels = label;
getlabel(label);
})
}
```

the response of above request is something like this

```
returned label { data: [ { id: '1721744167882031' }, { id: 
'1562439310518208' } ],
 paging:
 { cursors:
  { before: 'QVFIUldfeDVCVnBIOEo0Q3ZADZA2tIazNtUWxhNlpTUlhOVkQyU0NFZA1IzVGlnbGhJX2lCdWxuQUZAhYUlSaWlnZAFZAZAeU96Q3VrWGtCUHlaTnA1a0p5RmplNEh3',
    after:'QVFIUm1WRGVFcXRpSGh1RGtRQzd0eTZAGczZAlNUY5SmdFYUtsMEdSdmpYZAVJhWHVCRGdCQm9mU0lHbHg3X0NqbUc5QkhTNmswMm14WHRNZA3hWeDR0QkdkMTJB' } } }
```

after getting ids of label i take the id of first index from the returned data and use it to associate PSID to the label like so

```
function associatelabeltopsid(user, label, token) {
console.log('userid: ' + user + ' label :' + label);
var options = {
user: user,
uri: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/" + label + "/label?
access_token="+token,
}
requestpromise(options).then(function (response) {
console.log('association done', response);
 }).catch(function (error, response, body) {
if (error) {
  console.log("sending error", error.message);
} else if (response.body.error) {
  console.log("response body error senttext");
  console.log(response.body.error);
}
})
}
```

the three arguments of above function "associatelabeltopsid" are user=pagescope id of a recipient,label=[id on first index of the array returned in response from custom_labels endpoint], token={page access token}

the response of above request is something like this which leaves me incapable of associating my label with psid

```
sending error 400 - "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (label) on node type (PageUserMessageThreadLabel)\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"Esk6606yfRg\"}}"
```

what am i doing wrong here, why the request on endpoint custom_labels returns array of ids for label instead of single id, which one do i use, and how do i associate PSID to the label.

Comment: Sounds like you made a GET instead of a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment from @CBroe - you need to set `method: 'POST'` in your request options. The request-promise module will default to `GET` if `method` is not set.